# How can I get my URI of .mp3 file stored in res/raw folder in android

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I have a problem. I'd like to share my MP3 File to Whatsapp but it don't work! Here my Share Intent:

```
    public void shareAchieve() {
        Intent shareAchievement = new Intent();
        shareAchievement.setType("audio/*");
        shareAchievement.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://de.logtainment.ungesoundboard/" + R.raw.achieve + ".mp3"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareAchievement, "Teile Längstes Achievement"));
    }
```

But it doesnt work! Sorry for my bad english i'm from germany.

Comment: Very few apps support the `android:resource` scheme. If Whatapp does not support it, there is nothing you can really do to force them to do so. You will have better luck sharing a file rather than a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare Said ***Very few apps support the `android:resource` scheme***
To make your app compatible with all apps.

You have to copy your raw resource to Internal Storage by this method

```
private String CopyRAWtoSDCard(int raw_id,String sharePath) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(raw_id);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sharePath);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        return sharePath;
    }
```

Replace your method by below code

```
  public void shareAchieve() {
    Intent shareAchievement = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareAchievement.setType("audio/*");

    String sPath= null;
    try {
        sPath = CopyRAWtoSDCard(R.raw.filename, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/filename.mp3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(sPath);

    shareAchievement.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareAchievement.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareAchievement, "Teile Längstes Achievement"));
}
```

Also add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Which email client you used to send email? Gmail or other? could you please tell me?

Comment: For WhatsApp different code will work for Gamil different you looking for both?

Comment: I had looking for both

Comment: in my shareAchieve is the sharePath red! What's this? @Ishrat

Comment: I have made some changes after seeing your screenshot, please look at update answer.

Comment: Thanks @logtainment for accepting my answer, Please upvote my answer if it helped you.If you have any issue feel free to post on StakeOverFlow :)

Comment: But one question! How can i add the RAW files to my SD in a seperate folder? @Ishrat

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding /raw/ to the path and change your Intent like

change

```
Intent shareAchievement= new Intent();
shareAchievement.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://de.logtainment.ungesoundboard/" + R.raw.achieve + ".mp3"));
```

to

```
Intent shareAchievement= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareAchievement.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://de.logtainment.ungesoundboard/raw/achieve.mp3"));
```

Comment: When i Send a mail from Gmail to me. Gamil says that the attachment could not send! In Whatsapp also. @Fahim

Comment: Gmail says also, Attachment could not send! @Fahim

Comment: @logtainment did you tried making suggested changes

Comment: please try the suggested changes and let me know. According to me after applying this, it should work

Comment: No I have tried it it dosen't work. Gmail could not send the Attachment @Fahim

Comment: Unless you didn't try the changes, i won't be able to help you further